# get a path of text file present in my computer through core java code

Tags: java

I have text file but do not know the path where it saved in my computer.I only know name of the file. now how i get path of that file(Address/location) present in computer through java code.

Comment: Post your tried code, it will help us to resolve...

Comment: I found following code from internet but it searching only from c  File[] files = File.listRoots();
        for (File f : files) {
            parseAllFiles(f.getPath());           
        }

Answer (score 2):

Here is the to search the file on the computer

```
public class Operation {

              public static void main(String [] args) {
                  File[] files = File.listRoots();  
                    for(File f : files){  
                        System.out.println(f.getPath());
                        parseAllFiles(f.getPath());  
                    }  


                }

               public static void parseAllFiles(String parentDirectory) {  

                    String rootDir = System.getenv("SystemDrive");  

                    System.out.println("PARSED FILES ::" + rootDir);  

                    File[] filesInDirectory = new File(parentDirectory).listFiles();  
                    if(filesInDirectory!=null){
                    for (File f : filesInDirectory){      
                        if(f.isDirectory()){  
                            parseAllFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());  
                        }  
                       System.out.println("Current File -> " + f);    
                        System.out.println(f.getPath());  

                        File f1 = new File(f.getPath()+"infos.txt"); //name of file 

                        System.out.println("filename : " + f1.exists());  


                        boolean exists = f1.exists();  
                        System.out.println("exists : "+exists);  
                        if (exists) {  
                            System.out.println("Path::" + f1.getPath());  
                            break;
                        } else {  
                          System.out.println("Does not exist");  
                            }
                      }
                   }
               }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The java.nio.file package provides programmatic support for the features to find files and to do recursive search . Here is the java tutorial to help you achieve that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html